# How a PySpark program can use string as Spark dataframe?

Tags: string, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, attributeerror

```
df_source.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- industry_code_ANZSIC: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- unit: string (nullable = true)
```

If I tried to call the above dataframe using string it throws error as the above one is dataframe and below is the string

```
ls=['source','temp']
temp="df_"+ls[0]
print(temp)
# df_source
temp.printSchema()
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'printSchema'
> ```

I need some solution through which I could assign PySpark dataframe dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `exec`, but then you will have to write your method as string too:

```
exec(f"{temp}.printSchema()")
```